# Vertex AI Training model pipeline gets INTERNAL ERROR message

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have tried twice to start a training for tracking object in video, and both times, the session stops with above error after approx 8 hours of trying to train the model.

I have no idea how to proceed, and I worry for the cost - do you get billed for an internal error?

Google suggest me to post on here and hope that a Google team member might unofficïal help me?

Please....

Questions

Will internal error incidence be charged to me?
How do I rectify an internal error?
What went wrong in my training sessions?
What next step to take?

I tried different training sets, last time I went for 25 training videos, 1 label with appox 250 taggings.

PS BOTH training attempts failed after exact 8h 39m....

JOB ID
8559257530390282240 + 7089447978565369856

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.